# How to apply jQuery's load() function on page if I go to page via specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links at `index.html` to `target.html`.

first link is simple. it's just goes to target.html.

but I want to do something else with the second link.

simply:

1-user clicks the second link to target.html

**2-not only `target.html` appears but also `show-this-page-in-target.html-if-user-clicks-the-second-link.html` appears in `.page-class` element with the help of jQuery `load()` function.**

**What I'm able to do so far?**

I can load the page I want when I'm in target.html already with the codes below:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="load" class="btn btn-primary">Load</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#load').click(function(){
  $('.page-class').load('show-this-page-in-target.html-if-user-clicks-the-second-link.html .target-class')
}); 
</script>
```

But I don't know how to load them when I go that page via link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your second link to taget.html:

```
<a href="target.html#load" class="btn btn-primary">Load</a>
```

in target.html use this code:

```
<script>
if(window.location.hash === '#load') {
    $(function() {
        $('.page-class').load('show-this-page-in-target.html-if-user-clicks-the-second-link.html .target-class')
    });
}
</script>
```

Should work.